Why std::ranges::min_element returns an iterator instead of just the value?
Why std::ranges::min_element returns an iterator instead of just the value?

Imagine a scenario where you have a container of complex objects that are expensive to copy. Would you want the search to return a copy of the found element, or just an iterator to the element? More importantly, if the range is empty, what value should be returned?

@RemyLebeau That makes sense, thanks.

std::ranges::min returns the value. The _element variants are for when you want an iterator, not just the value.
